# Is snow a countable noun

Tags: determiners, modifiers, countability

I was reading news on Yahoo and got confused. I read this – **a snow** – on Yahoo; as per my opinion **snow is not a countable noun**. So, we should not use the article (a) before snow.

**This is from Yahoo:**

> If there's going to be **a snow** or rain storm the next morning, you
>   should probably get out the door sooner than usual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said, the article *a* in that sentence is modifying the word *storm*, not *snow*.

That said, it's worth pointing out that we **can** use an indefinite article before the word *snow*, even when the word *storm* doesn't follow. A bad snowstorm is often called *a big snow*, even without the word *storm*:

> We had **a big snow** in December, but the warm winds have melted most of the snow in the low range of mountains here. (*Climatological Data for the United States by Sections*, Volume 7, Jan. 1920)
>
> We had **a big snow** the night before that last game and it was like playing on concrete. (Todd Mishler, *Blood, Sweat, and Cheers: Great Football Rivalries of the Big Ten*, 2007)
>
> In Grandview, when **a big snow** came, it was a wholesale holiday for everybody. That way folks stayed safe, warm, and dry. (Robert Hill, *The Color of Sabbath*, 2007)

Similarly, we can say:

> We had **a huge rain** on Sunday, which has caused the river to rise.

In contexts such as these, phrases like "a big snow" and "a huge rain" are acceptable, shortened ways of saying "a large amount of snowfall" or "a huge amount of rain."

You are right when you say that *snow* is not a countable noun. But you are wrong if you think that all mass nouns can never be used in a countable context. English is too flexible to adhere to such rigid rules.